# Two player Poker hand Combinatorics

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A well-documented problem in early combinatorics is how many ways a certain poker hand (like a full house) can be drawn from a randomly shuffled deck of cards. I am confident I understand the details of this problem.

My question is regarding two players drawing from the deck. How many ways can I draw one hand and my opponent draw another. For example, I believe there are 1312 ways for both players to draw straight flushes. That is only one case and I am curious about the other 80 (81 total because 9 types of hands squared).

I am aware of the symmetry of these results so it is more like 45 cases.

In general, I think some or most of these are probably quite difficult to generate a formula for because the number of ways a second player can draw a hand is highly dependent on what was drawn first.

Regarding my question, I am curious if there are any resources regarding this or if any of you have ideas about this problem.

I was originally looking into generating the results using a computer program with some success (I have 34 / 81 figured out) but it quickly became apparent that it would take too long for some results so unless someone has an idea about simplifying the problem space, that option is out. The basic idea behind my algorithm is each card in the deck is a number between 0 and 51 inclusively so each hand is a set of 5 numbers in that range. Checking if it's possible to draw two given hands is equivalent to checking if those two sets are disjoint.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Trying to adapt the one hand problem with conditional probabilities is my best bet. Assume you know the first player's draw and go from there, for example for pair, trios and four of a kinds you just need to remove the relevant cards from the deck because it doesn't really matter what the remaining cards are, since they are equally likely to have any of them, and in that case the only pair/trio/quad that would be distinct is the ace one(since it only appears in 2 straights instead of the usual 5)